# Yaml to database

Tags: c++, sql, database, yaml, yaml-cpp

For my c++ program, I use `jobs.yml` which contains information about jobs in yaml format like:

```
141647523:
  JobType: Turbo
  LocalJobID: 16773779.0
  Status: Done
  SystemPriority: 0.0
  UserPriority: 8.0
```

Then I use [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) library for parsing file and casting jobs to c++ `Job` objects. Due to the big size of `jobs.yml` (~900Mb) I can't read all file at once at the beginning of the program and store in `RAM`.

How can I overcome this obstacle? 
I guess that I should convert `jobs.yml` to database and in the program get desired data through `sql` requests? In this case what I should do?

Or maybe there are available more simple solutions?

Comment: flyx has a good answer below, but consider also that a 1 GB YAML file is probably not the most efficient solution. Consider a binary format (e.g. SQLite, or something) - you'll probably see massive savings both in file size and load time.

Comment: @JesseBeder Do you have tutorial or some examples how to use `YAML::Parser.HandleNextDocument`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yaml-cpp has an event-based API. Just derive from `YAML::EventHandler` and use `YAML::Parser.HandleNextDocument`. Then process the events in your event handler one-by-one. This should save you from loading the whole file into RAM.

Comment: Do you have good examples of using `YAML::Parser.HandleNextDocument`? Or maybe some tutorial?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am not yaml-cpp user.